# irfanview show .mov videos in main window

Tags: video, quicktime, irfanview

I'm using irfanview as my main image viewer, however I'm a bit annoyed by the fact that .mov files (from my smartphone) are played in an external window (either quicktime or the other external video player).

The windows that open up are weirdly scaled and often the "close" button is outside of the screen space, thus making it hard to close.

Is there a way to show videos in the main irfanview window? (and if not is there an equivalent image viewer that can?)

Comment: Free File Viewer is an option ==> http://file.org/free-download/free-file-viewer. VLC is another option ==> http://filehippo.com/download_vlc_64